# Try/except to cleanup a large script

Tags: python

I am developing a python application. This is formed by the main.py script (~153 lines of code) full of functions that are written in other scripts.

There is some cleanup code at the end, but I would like to run this cleanup even if an error is raised. Searching about this, I have seen approaches like this

```
try:
    # your program goes here
    # you're calling your functions from here, etc
except SystemExit:
    # do cleanup
    raise
```

This means I have to introduce basically all scripts (from the first function to the end) between `try` and `except`. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: You should probably use `finally:` instead of `except SystemExit:`, but yes.

Comment: Note that `your program goes here` can consist of calling *one* function (which calls all other functions).

Comment: you would catch `SystemExit` if your script has calls to `sys.exit()`, in order to do something just before completing the exit.  use a `finally` clause to cleanup in case of any (or no) exception... i.e. in all cases

Comment: You would normally write a function, maybe called `main` (your choice) and put all code in there that then call the function after the try. In larger projects you would have this code in a different file and import it.

Answer (score 3):

To run something regardless of error or not.
you can use the finally

```
try:
  print(x)
except:
  print("Something went wrong")
finally:
  print("The 'try except' is finished")
```

Comment: don't use a bare `except` tho

Comment: For this particular case it might be appropriate though (i.e. print details of any unhandled error before crashing). You could also omit the `except` and just have `try/finally` (which would hide that an error occurred... maybe not so good)

Comment: @Anentropic try/finally without an except will not hide an error. It will just propagate normally.

Comment: @Sören you are correct of course, oops!  In fact what I said is pretty much backwards... with the `except` you can hide the error (or print something) and without it you'll get unhandled error e.g. traceback in the console

Comment: Thanks all. I have seen the finally thing but this not a solution again I should add all my code between the try/except/finally code.

Comment: I was thinking something like another script that run after main.py whatever happens. If this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Reading suggestions. So far the best approach I have found is this

```
try:
   run_application()
   # This is a function that takes all functions contain in main.py
except:
    print('something went wrong')
finally:
    do cleanup

# This is at the end of the main.py script
```

Comment: Another thing I am thinking (but I am not going to do because it is a lot of work) is to add try/except in all functions used by my application. Is this a pythonic way to work?

Comment: please don't add your own answer which is just someone else's answer - this could just be a comment on RafaelMafra's that suggests doing try/except/finally

Comment: for the situation you originally asked about (always cleanup before exiting even if something went wrong) it probably makes most sense to have a top-level try/except/finally around a call to single main function

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys


try:
    print('my code')
 
# "type" of exception depends of Your script for example StandardError
except StandardError as err:
    print('ERROR: {}'.format(err))
    sys.exit(1)

#do cleanup
print('all OK')
print('cleanup code')
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: What's a StandardError?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-to-exceptions